# Ribbon shape using for loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I've been trying all day creating different for loop combinations in c++ and I can't seem to get the right one.

I want my output to look like this:

[Ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mmmv.png)

How can you display this without using arrays?

EDIT: I tried like this but I can't replicate it on the opposite end. This has been so far the closest output I've got.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    cout<<"*";

    for(int j = 5; j > i; j--)
    {
        cout<<" ";
    }

    for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
    {
        cout<<"*";
    }

    cout<<endl;

}
```

OUTPUT:

[Fail ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8zNN.png)

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question. It might be helpful to show some things that you have tried if they were close to working.

Answer (score 0):

You have nine lines; let's number them 0 to 8. Line number *n* contains:

- `1 + (4 - abs(4 - n))` asterisks (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
- `2 * abs (4 - n)` spaces (8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
- `1 + (4 - abs(4 - n))` asterisks (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

Answer (score -2):

One option is to increment the number of stars on each row, then go back down once you reached the midpoint.

```
void printChar(char c, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        std::cout << c;
}

int main()
{
    const int len = 10;

    int stars = 0;

    while (++stars <= len / 2)
    {
        int spaces = len - stars * 2;

        printChar('*', stars);
        printChar(' ', spaces);
        printChar('*', stars);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    stars--;
    while (--stars > 0)
    {
        int spaces = len - stars * 2;

        printChar('*', stars);
        printChar(' ', spaces);
        printChar('*', stars);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post a chunk of code as an answer with no explanation or even comments. Especially for homework questions like this. How will the OP ever learn anything from copying a complete solution verbatim?